# JQuery Live validation callback issue in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-validate, livevalidation

here is the code that handles the validation callback:

```
    $(".submission-validate").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
            $('#submit').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('#pleasewait').fadeIn('fast');
            });   
        }
    });
```

It works perfectly fine on other browsers, but nothing happens when I click submit in Safari. If I remove the submitHandler, it works fine. Please help me sort this issue out.

Also, I read up on some articles that there is about a 40% chance that a form with files for upload will hang or get stuck and show no activity. I also read up that the solution to it would be to send a connection close header or something. Please help me make this possible in my form too.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Simply rename your submit button's name into something other than 'submit'.

Wrong submit button name:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Correct submit button name:

```
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" />
```